# Removing/Replacing JFrame window?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I want to replace a JFrame (which contains a JPanel) if the user types the letter "N".

My current code just adds a new JFrame but doesn't remove the previous one.

Here is my `Frame.java` class:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    public Frame() {
        add(new Panel());
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And here is my `Panel.java` class:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public Panel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        setFocusable(true);

        addKeyListener(new PanelKeyListener());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Paint things
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    class PanelKeyListener implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_N:
                    JFrame frame = new Frame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    break;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the key bindings API over KeyListener, it solves the focus related issues that KeyListener suffers from. Consider using CardLayout over multiple frames

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to replace the JFrame, you can open a new one and close it with:

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

Or by:

```
frame.setVisible(false); 
frame.dispose();
```

But, it's very strange to replace a JFrame. Usually, we change the content of the frame (with setContentPanel) and not the frame itself :)

```
frame.setContentPanel(new OtherPanel())
```

Personnaly, I would change your code to:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setContentPane(new MyPanel(frame)); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private Frame refFrame; 
    public MyPanel(Frame frame) {
        this.refFrame = frame; 

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        setFocusable(true);

        addKeyListener(new PanelKeyListener());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Paint things
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    class PanelKeyListener implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_N:
                    refFrame.setContentPane(new OtherPanel()); 
                    break;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would this code go in my program? Within `main()` or within the keypress? Also, you mention that normally the content of the frame is changed. How would that be done?

Comment: There are a lot of different way to do that. One should be to give a reference to the JFrame in the constructor of the panel. That reference would be saved in a field. Then, in your key listener you can call ```frameField.setContentPane(new CustomPanel())```

(I will add a sample code snippet to my answer, just wait a minute ;) )

Comment: How would I reference `Frame` in the `Panel` class constructor? :/